# Does my lambda function go inside my main python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I don't know how to write a Lambda. Here is my main_script.py that executes 2 stored procedures. It inserts records every day then finds the difference between yesterday's and today's records and writes them to a table.

```
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import os 
import json

class className:
    env=None
    config=None

    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env=env_filename
        self.config=self.get_config()

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)

    def DB_connection(self):
        config=className.get_config(self)
        username=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_username"]
        password=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_password"]
        host=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_host"]
        port=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_port"]
        database=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["aws_secret_db"]

        return pm.connect(
            user=username,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            database=database
        )

    def run_all(self):
        def test_function(self):
            test_function_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_test_insert();"
            test_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_test_exceptions();"
            test = self.config["exceptions"]["functions"]["test_function"]
            if test:
                with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                    with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                        try:
                            cur.execute(test_function_INSERT_QUERY)
                            print("test_function_INSERT_QUERY insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount))

                            cur.execute(test_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                            print("test_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount))

                        except pm.Error as e:
                            print(f"Error: {e}")

                        except Exception as e:
                            logging.exception(e)

                        else:
                            cnxn.commit()
        test_function(self)

def main():
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    vfc=(cwd+"\_config"+".json")
    ve=className(vfc)
    ve.run_all()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Would I write my lambda_handler function inside my script above or have it as a separate script?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #some code
```

Answer (score 5):

I would treat `lambda_handler(event, context)` as the equivalent of `main()`  with the exception that you do not need `if __name__ ...` clause because you never run a lambda function from the console.

You would also need to use `boto3` library to abstract away AWS services and their functions.  Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html) to get started.

As the first order of business, I would put the DB credentials out of the file system and into a secure datastore.  You can of course configure Lambda environment variables, but [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) is more secure and super-easy to call from the code, e.g.:

```
import boto3
ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-east-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    password = ssm.get_parameters(Names=['/pathto/password'], WithDecryption=True)['Parameters'][0]['Value']
    return {"password": password}
```

There is a more advanced option, the [Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html), which for a little money will even rotate passwords for you (because it is fully integrated with [Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_how-services-use-secrets_RDS.html)).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I am using the Secrets Manger to store my DB info. I'm not sure what goes inside the lambda. The secrets manager is a different function I am going to write, so what do I put in the lambda? the logging information? i am trying to log to cloudwatch. and I have main() because it executes my function above :/